# How to add and delete an object item in react state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to   add or delete object to another object through react state. How can I achieve this?

code is like this:

```
const [ stateObj, setStateObj ] = usetState({
   obj1: {},
   obj2: {},
   obj3: {}
})
```

I want to add  some objects temp1,temp2,temp3,... inside obj1, such as:

```
setState({ ...stateObj, obj1: {...obj1,temp1} })
setState({ ...stateObj, obj1: {...obj1,temp2} })
...
```

but this seems not correct, this keeps obj1 one item only
how can I add temp1,temp2,... into obj1 by state?
and also the method for delete temp1, temp2,...?

Comment: You code will give error, is `obj1` accsseble?

Comment: Are `temp1` and `temp2` objects too? Do you want to merge `temp` objects properties or just add it as a new property?

Comment: yes , obj1 is accessible

Comment: temp1 and temp2 are also object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be careful we should copy the state first:

> Never mutate state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat state as if it were immutable.

```
  const temp1 = { a: 1 };
  const temp2 = { b: 2, c: 3 };
  const prevState={...stateObj};
  const newObj1 = { ...prevState.obj1, ...temp1, ...temp2 };
  setStateObj({ ...prevState, obj1: newObj1 });
  console.log(stateObj);
```

here is an example just with javascript

```js
 const stateObj = {
    obj1: {},
    obj2: {},
    obj3: {}
  };
  const temp1={a:1};
  const temp2={b:2,c:3};
  const newObj1={...stateObj.obj1,...temp1,...temp2};
  const updatedState={...stateObj,obj1:newObj1}
  console.log(updatedState)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

```
setStateObj(prevState = > {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        obj1: {
            ...obj1,
            temp1
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling setState simultaneously, so the state is updated only once with the last value. setState is batched together as it is not synchronous. You have to update the state with the previous state